# Does Lightning Network has concept of continuous stream of value?

Tags: lightning-network, micropaymentchannels, channels

Examples:

- Car insurance: $1000 per year.
- Legal consultation: $500 per hour.
- Visiting a website: $100 per hour.

Assuming `1 BTC = $8000`

`1 hour = $100 = 0.0125 BTC = 1,250,000 sat`

`1 second = 1,250,000 sat / 3600 = 347.22 sat`

I could generate a new invoice and pay it every second.

#### Continous stream of value?

I was thinking about something else:

> until further notice, please charge me 3472.22 sat per second

To avoid me going offline, there could 10 second heartbeat.

#### Is it overcomplicated?

Because of speed of light limit and network propagation, `1s` resolution is good enough, no need for a continous stream of value.

Issuing a new invoice every second is a simple workaround and no need to overcomplicate.

**Or maybe it exists natively?**

**EDIT / UPDATE:** https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/wiki/Brainstorming#streaming-payments

Answer (score 2):

Streaming payments is not part of the lightning network protocol yet.

However you can build a lightning app that simulates exactly this. There was a demo by alekos Filini on lädt years lightning residency. Check out https://youtu.be/IlSVTir_9Ns

When AMP is coming streaming payments could be stimulated with AMP by setting up more and more routes. But that would be rather fancy.

So I guess you create an app on top of lightning to solve streaming payments

Comment: *However you can build a lightning app that simulates exactly this.* - I'm stealing this idea. Not exactly stealing because I feel partially responsible of thinking about it, just not being fully aware if this is already a part of the protocol... Also related: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/issues/399 *(seems like the receiving node needs to create the invoice first in order to receive a payment)*